# How to use log4j.properties to create a log file for a Java Web Service without using an absolute path

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, logging, absolute-path

I'm trying to create a log file for a JAX-WS. I need to be able to build a WAR and put it on a Tomcat Server without anything else with it. This WAR will be used on many different servers where the paths to Tomcat may not always be the same. So the location of the log file has to be relative and possibly generate when the WAR is deployed. Right now my logging, even with an absolute path is not working. I have searched Stack Overflow and can't figure out what my problem is. Below is my code and thanks for the help.

**main file**

```
package lms.foodocs;

....

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class FooDocs{

      static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(FooDocs.class.getName());
      .....
      .....
      .....

      public String getPDF(String data){
         log.info("testing");
         return PDF(data);
      }



      private String PDF(String sourceData){
         try{
             ........
             ........

             log.info("test message);             }

         }catch(Exception e){
           log.error("Doc", e);
           return "crap";
          }
```

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout, R


log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;
log4j.appender.stdout.ConversionPattern =%5 [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=C:/workspace/foo.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.R,MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p -%m%n
```

**my paths**

```
WebContent/

  META-INF/

  WEB-INF/
    classes/
        lms/
          foodocs/
            FooDocs.class
            log4j.properties
     FooDocsService/
     lib/
      server.config.wsdd
      web.xml
      sun-jaws.xml

   wsdl/
      FooDocs.wsdl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change `C:/workspace/foo.log` to `${catalina.base}/logs/foo.log` in your log4j.properties file. This will write your log file to the `logs` directory of your Tomcat installation;
2. Move your log4j.properties file so that it is located immediately below the WEB-INF/classes/ directory.

Also, it's more conventional to declare your logger as:

```
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(FooDocs.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since tomcat always define catalina home you can use:

```
log4j.appender.R.File=${catalina.home}/logs/foo.log
```

You can also use some other system property or create your own custom property and pass it like this

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dfoo.logging.root=/foo/bar/"
```

and use it like this

```
log4j.appender.R.File=${foo.logging.root}/logs/foo.log
```